# x2go fails to trust my key on mac OS X, how can I solve it?

Tags: dialog, x2go

I installed the latest version of x2go from the official webpage. Putted the dmg into the application folder and opened the application.
I entered the information from the connection, they are correct, I double checked them and I'm able to connect through ssh with that same information. But this message keeps poppiong up after clicking yes every single time.

[image]

Which read in spanish 'This sever is unknown, trust its key? Hash of its public key:'

Which is a common message for a x2go connection. I click yes every time but it pops up again and again until I click no, then the a new dialog tells that the connection failed.

I checked the xquartz installation, it's the version 2.8.2.

Disconnected audio, printing etc...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this while I was writing the question so I might as well leave the answer here since I didn't find the solution for this problem anywhere else.

Starting to investigate it here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/487597/able-to-connect-by-ssh-but-not-x2go

The author talks about how to add a key manually into the folder ~/.ssh

While trying to access it by terminal it yielded the following prompt

```
cd .ssh
-bash: cd: .ssh: Permission denied
```

Trying to acces it I stumble across this thread

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146193/bash-cd-ssh-permission-denied

Just inputting this

```
chmod u+xr,go-rwx ~/.ssh
```

Was enough for x2go to work, it couldnt access the folder in the first place

PS: This solution allows x2go to work correctly, but makes ssh connection on the terminal unable to work. To return to the terminal settings one should do

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh
```

From one of the comments of this thread

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/494483/specifying-an-identityfile-with-ssh